# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when using datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate a date using two table. Here the query

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(varchar,D.BUSS_DATE, 23), convert(varchar,A.BUSS_DATE,23))
FROM dbo.TrxA1 A WITH (NOLOCK)  
LEFT JOIN SOURCE_TBL_MASTER_EXCHANGE_RATE_HISTORY D WITH (NOLOCK)       
ON A.CCY = D.SPOT_RATE
```

But I get the error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I have been converting those date columns to varchar but the error is still same.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I want to calculate the difference in days from table A and table B using datediff. in table A and B using the date format yyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss and I want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd and then calculate the difference between the two date columns. fyi those column in diffent table

Comment: what is the data type for `BUSS_DATE` in both table ?

Comment: The error might be coming from `ON A.CCY = D.SPOT_RATE` What is the data type for `CCY` and `SPOT_RATE` ?

Comment: If `BUSS_DATE` is a date datatype, you don't need to convert to `varchar` (and if you do, always specify the length of the varchar). `DATEDIFF` doesn't accept strings as arguments. And date datatypes have no format.

Comment: i have beed remove ON A.CCY = D.SPOT_RATE this one but the error still same. and i try to remove DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(varchar,D.BUSS_DATE, 23), convert(varchar,A.BUSS_DATE,23)) and change to the other one the query running well. i assume that the error coming from datediff

Comment: Some compulsory reading:[Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: When converting to varchar you should always specify the length, else you'll get the default which might not be what you want.

Comment: What's wrng with just `DATEDIFF(DAY, D.BUSS_DATE, A.BUSS_DATE)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be converting to *dates* not strings.  No conversion may be needed at all if your data is using the correct types:

```
select datediff(day, D.BUSS_DATE, A.BUSS_DATE)
from dbo.TrxA1 A left join
     SOURCE_TBL_MASTER_EXCHANGE_RATE_HISTORY D       
     on A.CCY = D.SPOT_RATE;
```

If your values are inappropriate stored as strings, you can convert using:

```
select datediff(day, convert(date, D.BUSS_DATE, 23), convert(date, A.BUSS_DATE, 23))
```

If you still have a problem, you can fix it using `try_convert()`:

```
select datediff(day, try_convert(date, D.BUSS_DATE, 23), try_convert(date, A.BUSS_DATE, 23))
```

But that just masks the problem.  You should find the offensive values:

```
select buss_date
from dbo.TrxA1 A 
where try_convert(date, buss_date, 23) is null and buss_date is not null;
```

Then fix the values *and change the data type to an appropriate date/time type*.

Finally, do not use `NOLOCK` unless you know what it is doing.  And you probably don't.  `NOLOCK` is a license that says:  "You can get me data from the table that is not 100% accurate."